# How to attach color variables to both storybook palette and components?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, sass, vite, storybook

I create UI components library and use Storybook to provide docs and examples for it.

My goal is to declare a color palette in SCSS file and use it in components as well as in storybook palette.

Storybook palette is a buil-in [storybook component](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/doc-block-colorpalette#page-top) that allows to make docs for your color palette.

So I expect that if a color of the design system is changed, then I can simply change the SCSS variable value and both color palette and components will be updated with the new color value.

Unfortunately storybook docs are poor in this part and examples include only hardcoded colors. The color palette page is MDX file, so I have no idea how I can import and use SCSS variables there.

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Came across this tonight when looking up the same issue I'm running in to. After some googling, I did also come across this: https://dev.to/benrobertson/color-swatches-in-storybook-4aa9. I haven't tried it yet, but thought I'd share in case you want to give it a go. I plan on testing it out over the weekend.